# JavaScript find all text nodes and return in a string

Tags: javascript, textnode

I need to define a function named getText() that finds all Text nodes at or beneath a specified node, and then extracts and concatenates the textual content of the nodes and returns it as a single JavaScript string. In getText() it will be an alert that is called

My body content will be:

```
<body onload="getText()">
<div id="divText">
<h4>This is a heading!</h4>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>And this is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer browsers you can use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) for this.

```
alert(document.getElementById('divText').textContent);
```

In older browsers you need to walk through the DOM with `.childNodes` and test, if a node has `nodeType === 3` (then it's a text node) or `nodeType === 1` (it's an element you need to traverse recursively, too).

You will also need this last solution, when you need to filter whitespace-only nodes, like the line breaks between tags.

Comment: Cheers, although it seems like cheating since we are being thought older JavaScript at uni. We are using the elements and .childnodes etc

Answer (score 0):

Are you adverse to using jQuery? ($('body').text()) may solve your problems if you do

Comment: No its just that it was an optional exercise for university work. I can debug a good bit of JavaScript and jQuery but never really wrote anything myself